# How to include a folder for linting that is not in root folder of eslintrc file?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have two projects that share common files from the common folder.

Now, I am trying to setup eslint so I can lint both the project folder and the common folder.

Folder structure is like this:

- MyProjectFolder
- .eslintrc.js
- ```
  src
  ```
- CommonFolder
- ```
  src
  ```

I am trying to add an `"override: [ files: ["src/**/*.js", "../CommonFolder/src/**/*.js"] }]`" to eslint with relative path, but eslint is telling me that it is an invalid override path.

So, does anyone know how I can add CommonFolder into .eslintrc.js file?

Answer (score 1):

If using VS-Code, you can add both directories to the ESLint working directory settings in the VS-Code Workspace Extensions settings.

1. cmd + shift + p / ctrl + shift + p
2. type workspace setting!
3. Select ESLint from the Extensions menu.
4. Look for the working directory configuration and open it in JSON format.
5. Include a directory path.

   ```
   {
      "eslint.workingDirectories": [
        "path1/",
        "path2/"
      ]
   }
   ```

you cant visit this link https://medium.com/devityoself/monorepo-eslint-vscode-6f5982c8404d

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by moving the .eslinrc.js config file to the parent folder which consists of both CommonFolder and ProjectFolder, and gave it a property of `root: true`.

If builder doesn't find a config file in it's root folder, it will begin searching parent folders until it finds a config file with root option set to true.

This way, both my projects can use only one eslint config file, even if they use different build files.

Answer (score 0):

The `.eslintrc*` file should work as expected on its own, but if you're using VS Code, it may not behave. The `eslint.workingDirectories` setting is what you probably want.

Just adding the folder path may not work. Consider using `mode`:

```json
"eslint.workingDirectories": [{ "mode": "auto" }]
```

According to the docs: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint#settings-options

> `[{ "mode": "auto" }]` (@since 2.0.0): instructs ESLint to infer a working directory based on the location of package.json, .eslintignore and .eslintrc* files. This might work in many cases but can lead to unexpected results as well.